# React---TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm following the react.js tutorial, and I keep running into this error 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' when the Tasks component is executed. What would cause this error?
Tasks component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Task from './Task';

class Tasks extends Component{
    render() {
        return this.props.tasks.map(task => <Task task={task} key={task.id} />); 
    }
}

export default Tasks;
```

Task component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Task extends Component {
    render(){
        const { task } = this.props;

        return <div>
           {task.title} - 
           {task.description} - 
           {task.done} - 
           {task.id}
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <button>x</button>
        </div>
    }

}

export default Task;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are calling `this.props.tasks.map` but there doesn't seem to be anywhere you pass in that tasks property to the Tasks component. Similar to how you are passing task into the Task component. Can you include the component that is using the Tasks component?

Comment: Please show the file where you are including the Tasks component

Comment: I already solved the problem, thank you very much! This community is amazing!

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

import tasks from './sample/tasks.json';

import Tasks from './components/Tasks';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    tasks : tasks
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks}/>
      
      
    </div>
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error `'Cannot read property 'map''` means that you trying to map a variable that is undefined, in your case, the variable `tasks`. Example:

```js
// OK
let props = {
  tasks: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
props.tasks.map(task => console.log(task)); // a, b, c

// Undefined
let props2 = {};
props2.tasks.map(task => console.log(task)); // Throw an error
```

In the first example, you have defined the variable `tasks`, so the map works.

In the second example, `tasks` is not defined, so when you try to `map`, this throw an error.

To overcome this, verify if the variable exists, before use the `map`:

```js
let props = {};

// Using ternary operator
props.tasks ? props.tasks.map(task => console.log(task)) : console.log('Ok'); // Ok

// Using if
if (props.tasks) {
  props.tasks.map(task => console.log(task));
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solution**

*1.* comment the line with the .map function, save the file, and reload the page

*2.* uncomment the line and do not reload the browser.

> NOTE: **You will have to repeat these procedures anytime you reload the browser.**